# Possible memory leak in webapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, memory-leaks

In my webapp I create some DOM elements based on page fragments sent by the server.
Any new fragment is a div with a unique ID generated within a jsp page.

I think register for events on elements within this div using a script tag also sent as part of the page fragment.

This is how my page fragment looks like.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   var myButton = $("#<unique_tab_id").find(".myButton);
   myButton.click(clickFunction);
   function clickFunction() {
   }
});
</script>

<div id="<unique_tab_id">
  <button class="myButton">
   My Button
  </button>
</div>
```

Over time several divs get added and removed from the page. The removal happens based on some user actions which just calls jquery replaceWith or remove functions.

New elements get added. I do not do anything to the events assuming jquery will automatically deregister them.

Is my assumption correct?
Can there be a possible memory leak with this coding style? I see my page slowing down after a while. It is due to increase in memory usage. Am I leaking memory here?

There are closures involved in the functions defined in $(document).ready(). But I am assuming they will no longer be active once the corresponding div is removed. Is that right?
What else could leak memory here.

If you would like to see more details here is the code:
https://github.com/C4G/V2V/blob/f4dd780ff5bf1d3b1d456d421602038500769fd9/war/WEB-INF/jsp/donors/addDonorForm.jsp

Comment: This depends on the browser, not on your programming style. Note that when you use Facebook and load lot (and I really mean a lot) of stories you get the same *slow down* behavior.

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell: jQuery's Cache object is known to have certain garbage collection issues, some of which get plugged by devs, some of which slip below the radar. There have been a couple of occurences in the past like:

- Events not being cleared from the jQ cache when the DOM node was de-registered
- the cache being beaten by a three-object circular reference and not doing garbage collection

Throw some code around and someone might test it. Right now, all I can provide is generics. Try to manually de-register all events from your objects before removing them (`off()` if you know what events you've bound), and see if the leak is still there.

How are you removing your objects? If you're setting `innerHTML=null`, your objects are most likely still in memory.

How are you tracing the memory leak? Might want to run the JS profiler in firebug to see if there actually IS a leak.

Comment: I am using replaceWith as shown in the code here:
https://github.com/C4G/V2V/blob/f4dd780ff5bf1d3b1d456d421602038500769fd9/war/WEB-INF/jsp/donors/addDonorForm.jsp#L55

Since this is on github you can see real code there if it helps you answer the question. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure with the above coding style (in the real example linked) I can be holding references to objects that are no longer needed.

Comment: BTW is `innerHTML=null` equivalent to `$("#elementId").html("");`
I am doing that at several places.